# Grails JSON marshaller for FieldErrors

Tags: grails, marshalling

I'm trying to create a custom marshaller for [org.springframework.validation.FieldError](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html) so I can avoid putting extraneous and possibly sensitive data in my JSON response, which includes `MyCommandObject.errors`.

However my FieldError marshaller isn't working at all, this is what I have in my BootStrap.groovy under the init method.

```
    def fieldErrorMarshaller = {
        log.info("field error marshaller $it")
        def returnArray = [:]

        returnArray['field'] = it.field
        returnArray['message'] = it.message

        return returnArray
    }

    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(FieldError, fieldErrorMarshaller)
```

I am not seeing any explicit errors or the marshaller logging. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to set a priority? `registerObjectMarshaller(java.lang.Class clazz, int priority, groovy.lang.Closure callable)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails register a instance of `ValidationErrorsMarshaller` that handle all errors, so your FieldError marshaller will never get called.

```
//convertAnother is not called for each error. That's the reason of your custom marshalled not been called.
for (Object o : errors.getAllErrors()) {
    if (o instanceof FieldError) {
        FieldError fe = (FieldError) o;
        writer.object();
        json.property("object", fe.getObjectName());
        json.property("field", fe.getField());
        json.property("rejected-value", fe.getRejectedValue());
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        if (applicationContext != null) {
            json.property("message", applicationContext.getMessage(fe, locale));
        }
        else {
        ...
```

Looking at `ConvertersGrailsPlugin` (descriptor of the plugin) this is registered as a Spring Bean, so you can create another bean and register with the same name, overriding the `marshalObject()` to fit your needs (not tested, may need more code).

```
class MyErrorsMarshaller implements ObjectMarshaller<JSON>, ApplicationContextAware {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public boolean supports(Object object) {
        return object instanceof Errors;
    }

    public void marshalObject(Object object, JSON json) throws ConverterException {
    ...
    }

}
```

**resources.groovy**

```
jsonErrorsMarshaller(MyErrorsMarshaller)

errorsJsonMarshallerRegisterer(ObjectMarshallerRegisterer) {
    marshaller = { MyErrorsMarshaller om -> }
    converterClass = grails.converters.JSON
}
```

Reference for [ValidationErrorsMarshaller](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/converters/marshaller/json/ValidationErrorsMarshaller.java).

Reference for [ConvertersGrailsPlugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/converters/ConvertersGrailsPlugin.groovy).

Comment: Thank you, it would have taken me forever to figure that out on my own

Answer (score 3):

For anyone curious, this is the validator I ended up writing in Bootstrap.groovy based off of Sérgio Michels' answer

```
def validationErrorsMarshaller = {
    return it.getAllErrors().collect {
        if (it instanceof FieldError) {
            Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
            def msg = messageSource.getMessage(it, locale)

            return [ field: it.getField(), message: msg ]
        }
    }
}

JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(ValidationErrors, validationErrorsMarshaller)
```

I was able to simplify this from the original Java marshaller by using messageSource, which is injected by adding `def messageSource` to the BootStrap class.

Answer (score 0):

```
//usage in grails controller
render domainObject.errors as JSON

//resources.groovy
jsonErrorsMarshaller(MyErrorsMarshaller)
errorsJsonMarshallerRegisterer(ObjectMarshallerRegisterer) {
    marshaller = { MyErrorsMarshaller om -> }
    converterClass = grails.converters.JSON
}

//grails.converters.JSON marshaller class
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.validation.ValidationErrors
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.ObjectMarshaller
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONWriter
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder
import org.springframework.validation.Errors
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError


class MyErrorsMarshaller implements ObjectMarshaller<JSON>, ApplicationContextAware {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public boolean supports(Object object) {
        return object instanceof Errors;
    }

    public void marshalObject(Object object, JSON json) throws ConverterException {
        JSONWriter writer = json.getWriter();
        try {
            List<ObjectError> errors = ((ValidationErrors)object).getAllErrors()
            writer.object();
            writer.key("errors").array();
            Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
            for(FieldError error : errors){
                FieldError fe = (FieldError) error;
                writer.object();
                writer.key("field").value(fe.getField()).key("message").value(applicationContext.getMessage(fe, locale));
                writer.endObject();
            }
            writer.endArray();
            writer.endObject();
        } catch (ConverterException ce) {
            throw ce;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw new ConverterException( "Error converting Bean with class " + object.getClass().getName(), e);
        }
    }
}
```